# How to prove by induction that given a set $S$ of $n$ elements, the number even subsets of $S$ equals to the number of odd subsets?

Tags: combinatorics, induction

How do I prove by induction that given a positive integer $n\ge1$ and a set $S$ of $n$ elements, the number even subsets of $S$ equals to the number of odd subsets? For example, for $S=\{g,c\}$ there are two subsets with even cardinality: the empty set $\varnothing$ and $\{g,c\}$, as well as two subsets with odd cardinality: $\{g\}$ and $\{c\}$.

Comment: Well, break the subsets into two types, those that contain $n$ and those that don't.  Use the fact that we know the claim for $n-1$.

Comment: @lulu: We don't need the claim for $n-1$. When $n=1$ the claim for $n-1$ is in fact wrong.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter  The OP wanted to use induction.  $n=1$ is the (trivial) base case.  I agree that non-inductive arguments are preferable.

Answer (score 2):

Since $n\ge 1$ and is finite, you know there is at least one element of $S$.  Suppose one such is $a$.

Then the number of odd subsets of $S$ which contain $a$ is equal to the number of even subsets which do not contain $a$, and  the number of even subsets of $S$ which contain $a$ is equal to the number of odd subsets which do not contain $a$.

Adding the numbers together implies the number of odd subsets of $S$ equals the number of number of even subsets of $S$.

(This will not work when $n=0$, and the proposition would not be true as $\emptyset$ has one even subset but no odd subset).

The argument above does not use induction.  If you must use induction then

- The proposition is true when $n=1$ since there is one odd subset and one even subset (the empty set)
- Then the number of odd subsets of $S$ which contain $a$ is equal to the number of even subsets which do not contain $a$ which (by the inductive hypothesis) is equal to the number of odd subsets which do not contain $a$ and that is equal to the number of even subsets of $S$ which contain $a$.  Adding the pairs up proves the induction step.

Answer (score 2):

By the binomial theorem,
$$0=(1-1)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{(-1)^k \binom{n}{k}},$$ which leads to $$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{4} +\cdots=\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{3}+\binom{n}{5} +\cdots.$$
The left side is the number of ways of choosing an even subset and the right side is the number of ways of choosing an odd subset. They are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Let ${\cal P}_n$ be the power set of $[n]$. Then $|{\cal P}_0|=1$.

For any $A\in{\cal P}_n$ we obtain two elements of ${\cal P}_{n+1}$, namely $A$ and $A\cup\{n+1\}$. One of them is even, the other odd.